# How do i convert a ascii python string to its trinary representation

Tags: python-3.x, string, text, ascii, radix

Im trying to encode text in a dna format, which only has a,t and g, in the most compact way possible.

I have tried converting the string into binary, then int and then trinary but the ascii text “corrupts” into gibberish when the binary is converted into int via int(binary,2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution

```py
def asciiToTrinary(chars):
    result = []
    for char in chars: #covnvert to trinary(revrersed)
        currResults=[]
        n = ord(char)
        while n:
            n, r = divmod(n, 3)
            currResults.append(str(r))
        currResults=currResults[::-1]
        result.append("".join(currResults))
    result=result[::-1] #idk what this does but code breakes without it
    result.reverse() #reverse
    trinary=[]
    for char in result: #add padding
        char=(8-len(char))*"0"+char
        trinary+=char
    return "".join(trinary)

def trinaryToAscii(trinary):
    trinary=[trinary[i:i+8] for i in range(0, len(trinary), 8)] #break into chunks of 8
    chars=""
    for char in trinary:
        chars+=chr(int(char,3))
    return chars
```